# Generalization of Ito's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If $f:R\to R$ is a convex function then we have Ito-Tanaka formula. Now my question is that if we are given a function $u: R\times R_+\to R$ such that $u(s,\cdot)$ is smooth for every $s\in R$ and $u(\cdot, l)$ is convex for every $l\in R_+$. Could we have a formula like Ito-Tanaka formula? If some knows a related reference please let me know. Thx! In particular, if $u=u(s,l)$ is given by

$$u(s,l)=a(l)s^+,$$

where $a: R_+\to R$ is smooth and $s^+=\mathbf{1}_{s\ge 0}s$. How to apply Ito-Tanaka formula to $u(B_t, L_t)$? Here $B=(B_t)$ is a standard Brownian motion and $L=(L_t)$ is the local time of $B$ in zero. Thx a lot for the reply!

Comment: Good night, I need also the same generalized Ito-Tanaka formula but I do not find some references. Kindly, if you got this formula in any manuscript or book inform me.